# Comparing 3 different .csv files in R and extracting the common data between them to a new .csv

Tags: r, csv, shiny, data-science

I have a scenario where I want to compare 3 different .csv files and extract/write the data which is common in them to a 4th file.Can anyone advise me how to achieve this in R.

Comment: try `?merge` `?read.csv` `?write.csv` and check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dplyr to perform all operations in one pipe.

If you are looking for a solution finding observations that are present in ALL .csv files you should go with inner join:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

read.csv("first.csv") %>%
  inner_join(read.csv("second.csv")) %>%
  inner_join(read.csv("third.csv")) %>%
  write.csv("fourth.csv", quote = F, row.names = F)
```

If you are looking for a solution that find all observations present in ANY data frame you should go with full join:

```
read.csv("first.csv") %>%
  full_join(read.csv("second.csv")) %>%
  full_join(read.csv("third.csv")) %>%
  write.csv("fourth.csv", quote = F, row.names = F)
```